# get around cookies with requests + python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm very much a noob in python and scraping. I understand the basics but just cannot get past this problem.

I'm trying to scrape content from www.tweakers.net using python with the requests and beautifullsoup libraries. However, when I scrape, I keep scraping the cookie statement instead of the actual site content. Hope that there is anyone who can help me with code. I got run down with similar issues on other websites so would really like to understand how I can tackle such an issue. This is what I have now.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from requests.cookies import cookiejar_from_dict


last_agreed_time = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
url = 'www.tweakers.net'

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30'}
    session.cookies = cookiejar_from_dict({
        'wt3_sid': %3B318816705845986
        'wt_cdbeid': 68907f896d9f37509a2f4b0a9495f272
        'wt_feid': 2f59b5d845403ada14b462a2c1d0b967
        'wt_fweid' 473bb8c305b0b42f5202e14a
})
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    soup.prettify()`
```

Do not mind the content of the header, I ripped it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the best imports for scraping would be selenium or cookielib. Here is a link to selenium, http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html, and cookielib, https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html.

```
## added selenium code
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'www.tweakers.net'
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(url)
#add needed cookies
driver.add_cookie({'wt3_sid': %3B318816705845986
        'wt_cdbeid': 68907f896d9f37509a2f4b0a9495f272
        'wt_feid': 2f59b5d845403ada14b462a2c1d0b967
        'wt_fweid' 473bb8c305b0b42f5202e14a})
##this would be to retrieve a cookie
print(driver.get_cookie('string'))
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.content)
    soup.prettify()
```